# How does browser pickup the right font file via font-family value?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I copied some new fonts files , Apple's PingFang files, many .ttf files,  to my CentOS /usr/share/fonts dir and rebuild the font cache via command fc-cache -fv , it seems success. But when I run fc-match 'PingFang', the result is not the newly installed font file. What is the matter?

Another related question is , for the Apple's PingFang family , there are many files, like PingFang Bold.ttf  PingFang ExtraLight.ttf  PingFang Heavy.ttf  PingFang Light.ttf  PingFang Medium.ttf  PingFang Regular.ttf, what is the right family name for each font file if I want the browser render using specific font file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For putting a local .ttf font in your css and specifying bold, medium, or whatever style in the family, where font-family below is the alias of the specified weight:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "PingFang";
    src: url("PingFang-Medium.ttf") format('truetype'); 
}
```

Comment: this will ask browser to download the font file from server ,right? I don't want this, because in my case, the machine which running the browser does have those font files installed.

Comment: Correct. The font file will need to be transferred to the client in order to render the font.

Comment: @JTery, so how can I ask the browser to user locally installed font file inside  css definition as your suggested , via font-face's src section, I found the src value has an option is local(), what should I put inside the local()? font file name? or font family name? or postscriptname ?